# Impossible to empty trash with old Mac OS installer

Tags: mac, installer, trash

I've downloaded an old Mac OS installer to my laptop (to be installed on another older Mac): this Mac OS installer doesn't run on my MacBookPro since it way too old, therefore it's icon is crossed. The problem is that it not possible to empty the trash since Mac OS says the app is still in use... checked all the open apps and seems none are open ??!! Tried to empty the trash from Terminal and doesn't work either.

Any help ? Thanks !

Comment: Did you reboot yet?

Comment: Yes, I did many times.

Comment: Anyone got a clue how to solve the problem ?

Comment: Try starting in safe mode